# Error while connecting real iOS device with Appium server

Tags: ios, xcode, selenium, appium-ios

I'm trying to open the application from Appium server and getting the below mentioned error.

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Unknown device or simulator UDID:
>   '046e4469d6cb14ff57e378599bd4b1d09390472b'

```
 {
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPad",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "udid": "046e4469d6cb14ff57e378599bd4b1d09390472b",
  "bundleId": "com.***",
  "platformVersion": "11.2.6",
  "app": "/Users/***/***.ipa"
}
```

even tried with app location on my Mac machine but getting the same error.

```
xcode version:9.2

ios version:11.2.6

Mac OS version:10.13.3

Appium server version:1.7.2
```

Comment: you also need to add - “app”: "" - location of your app's file on machine

Comment: I have already tried with app location as well but still the same error

Comment: have you used platformVersion?

Comment: yep tried. Updated my q with the values

Answer (score 0):

configuration which is required -

```
{
 “platformName”: “iOS”,
 “platformVersion”: “10.2.1",
 “deviceName”: “------”,
 “udid”: “fdbe0d55ced1fd6fa842681b6a058438573fb762",
 “app”: “/Users/----/---/---/---.ipa”,
 “automationName”: “XCUITest”
}
```

Based on app path, it will find the app to be loaded, also you have to provide the iOS version(XCode ios simulator version for simulator/ device OS version for device).

Comment: I tried with iOS version and app path and have updated my question with both the values but still getting the same error.

Comment: there is some other configuration issue,  can you check github page to validate, you are using all correct config. - https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md

Comment: I have followed the above mentioned steps and now getting the following error. Pls help me with this.

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.

Comment: This error generally occurs when there is an issue with provisioning, can you check if your web driver xcodeproj has valid provisioning selected?

Comment: the issue has been resolved. It was due to the webdriveragent project in my machine. Thanks all for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

here is the iOS cap config,

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone");
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
 capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
 capabilities.setCapability("udid", “******************************”);
 capabilities.setCapability("bundleId”,”********”);
 capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
 capabilities.setCapability("app", “*******app path******“);
 driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

please make sure the UDID you have mentioned it correct ,
and you do need to add "WebDriver Agent" app in your iOS device.

Comment: can u help me with webdriveragent part?

Comment: For deploying webDriverAgent , here are the commands -   
 1. brew install carthage
 2. npm install -g ios-deploy
 3. gem install xcpretty